# For copies the first result only not the whole list

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel sheet "XLSX" I have a various number of columns.

First I search for the column titles "Anwendung" and "Profil-BenutzerId". After that I want to copy all fields from "Profil-BenutzerId" where the value in "Anwendung" is "S6" into a new Excel sheet "Rollen_Para".

My code is copying the first result where these conditions are true but I want to copy the whole list.

```
Sheets("XLSX").Select

    Dim h As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    For h = 1 To 39
    For i = 1 To 39
    If Cells(19, h).Text = "Anwendung" And Cells(19, i).Text = "Profil-BenutzerId" Then
    For j = 20 To 1048576
    If Cells(j, h) = "S6" Then
    Cells(j, i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Rollen_Para").Select
    Cells(j - 18, 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End If
    Next
    End If
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can there be more than once column with header Anwendung and more than one with Profil-BenutzerId ?

Comment: No both colum titles could only appear once.

Comment: Will only appear once?

Comment: I mean there is only one column title that is named Anwendung and there is only one column title that is named Profil-BenutzerId in the whole file so the titles will only appear once in the whole file.

Comment: The answer given should help though I would use union to gather the qualifying rows if possible so as to paste in one go. Also, switch of things like screen updating , calculation mode to manual..... how many rows typically are we talking  here?

Comment: We are talking about a little bit more than 10000 rows. Yes i tried that one below but afterwards my whole Excel file crashed and it was not responding anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? You can use Find to avoid most of those loops. I hope I have it the right way round. I have omitted the borders as not pertinent to your problem and can easily be added in later.

```
Sub x()

Dim j As Long
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

With Sheets("XLSX")
    Set r1 = .Rows(19).Find("Anwendung",,, xlWhole)
    Set r2 = .Rows(19).Find("Profil-BenutzerId")
    If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing Then
        For j = 20 To .Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(j, r1.Column) = "S6" Then
                .Cells(j, r2.Column).Copy Sheets("Rollen_Para").Cells(j - 18, 2)
            End If
        Next j
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately it is not working and my Excel program is crashing after I tried it with your suggestion.

Comment: Do you get an error message and if so on which line? Does the code do anything? I did a quick test and it seemed to work ok.

Comment: Yes now it works thank you very much! I had a Problem with my Excel file after Fixing this Problem it worked as expected.